# Adding ImageView to Listview Fragment / Master-Detail project template

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I've create a new fragment containing a listview using the Master-Detail project template from Google. I need to now add an imageView to the listView items however I'm unable to find an example of how this can be accomplished.

I've attempted to use:

```
addItem(new DummyItem("1", "Home", image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon)));
```

However I continually end up with errors stating:

The constructor Content.DummyItem(String, String, void) is undefined

P.S.

Following eclipse's suggestion to add:

```
public DummyItem(String id2, String content2, Object setImageResource) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

...simply leads to more errors. (I just need a quick hand with this - it's my first time using fragments so I just need a quick hand getting the basics down.)

### Source:

```
public class Content {
    static ImageView image;
    /**
     * An array of sample (dummy) items.
     */
    public static List<DummyItem> ITEMS = new ArrayList<DummyItem>();

    /**
     * A map of sample (dummy) items, by ID.
     */
    public static Map<String, DummyItem> ITEM_MAP = new HashMap<String, DummyItem>();

    static {
        // Add 3 sample items.
        addItem(new DummyItem("1", "Home", image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon)));
        addItem(new DummyItem("2", "Before & After Photos", image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon)));
        addItem(new DummyItem("3", "Video Testimonials", image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon)));
        addItem(new DummyItem("4", "Audio Testimonials", image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon)));
        addItem(new DummyItem("4", "Written Testimonials", image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon)));
    }

    private static void addItem(DummyItem item) {
        ITEMS.add(item);
        ITEM_MAP.put(item.id, item);
    }

    /**
     * A dummy item representing a piece of content.
     */
    public static class DummyItem {
        public String id;
        public String content;
        private Object object;

        public DummyItem(String id, String content, Object setImageResource) {
            this.id = id;
            this.content = content;
            this.object = object;
        }


        public DummyItem(String id2, String content2, Object setImageResource) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }


        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return content;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`setImageResource()` has a return type of `void` which means it doesn't return anything. What you probably should do is instead pass the resource ID itself and store that as an `int` in your DummyItem. Then in your list adapter you would call `setImageResource()` on an `ImageView` that is present in your list item layout.

```
public static class DummyItem {
    public String id;
    public String content;
    public int imageResource;

    public DummyItem(String id, String content, int imageResource) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
        this.imageResource = imageResource;
    }
}

// elsewhere...
addItem(new DummyItem("1", "Home", R.drawable.icon));
```

Comment: I just ran the code... and I don't see the images for some reason :(

Comment: Is there anything I need to do in XML?

Comment: Yes I have. What would you suggest I do.

Comment: Your list item layout needs an ImageView. Your list adapter needs to call setImageResource on that imageView somewhere during getView().

Comment: I don't have anything in my source referring to getView I'm not sure what you mean. 

(apologies if I'm missing something blatantly obvious - I'm very new to using Android fragments)

Comment: My guess is you are using a framework provided list adapter (or, if this code came from a template, the template makes use of one). Since you want to modify the adapter, you will need to stop using the framework provided one and make your own. I suggest you watch this video called _The World of ListView_ to understand working with ListView: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQtwIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DwDBM6wVEO70&ei=nldLU_SRO8Sa8AGPt4GABQ&usg=AFQjCNGAklAgezvQNN0PVmomzRjd7ci2uQ&sig2=Q92fBwyd_NEWmfSgHr3SkQ

Answer (score 0):

Have you create a CustomAdapter for your ListView?

you have DummyItem as a model that store your Image Resources, next we put all resource to the ListView with CustomAdapter, [here](http://pastebin.com/GMWTCrbV) the code

Don't forget to set Adapter on your ListView

```
DummyAdapter adapter =  new DummyAdapter(this.getActivity, ITEMS);
dummyList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I attempted your suggestion - I'm not sure exactly what I did wrong - but I'm getting a handful of errors when I attempted to do so (I tried to include as much info as possible - apologies if it's overkill)

http://pastebin.com/gAR5RQSr

Comment: Dears where is your ListView, I'm bit confused with your code
Please refer to this tutorial if you want to know using CustomAdapter on ListView
http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92